# loop through JSON using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I am trying to loop through a json object for the first time, all I want to do is list the all the contents of the temp variable but I can't figure how to the loop to work.

```
$("button").click(function(){
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=53.7&lon=0.3&callback=?" ; 
$.getJSON(url, function(res) {

    $('#result').html('<p>lon: ' + res.city.coord.lon + '</p>'); 
    $('#result').append('<p>lat: ' + res.city.coord.lat + '</p>');
    $('#result').append('<p>wind: ' + res.wind.speed + '</p>');

        $.each(res.list.main, function(i, temp) {
            $('#result').append('<p>temp: ' + temp[i] + '</p>');
        });
});
```

});

Comment: `temp` is the value, don't need the brackets `[]`

Comment: what have you tried to determine what is happening during your $.each callback?

Answer (score 1):

You should really console.log your object and figure out the structure.

There is no `res.wind.speed` in that object at the location where you think it is.

Here's an overview of your object -> ***http://jsfiddle.net/t2KMk/1/***

notice that `list` is an array of objects for different times etc. containing such things as wind, clouds, rain, main etc.

Here's an example of how to iterate over those values, getting the wind

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=53.7&lon=0.3&callback=?"; 

    $.getJSON(url, function(res) {
        $('#result').html('<p>lon: ' + res.city.coord.lon + '</p>'); 
        $('#result').append('<p>lat: ' + res.city.coord.lat + '</p>');

        $.each(res.list, function(i, temp) { // iterate the array

            $('#result').append('<p>wind: ' + temp.wind.speed + '</p>');
                                     //              ^^^ here you have wind
        });
    });  
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2KMk/)